# Fixing Markup Errors due to Shortcodes in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, validation, markup

Its me, the css / html fool again :D.

No joking - i got a few frustrating problems in numbers they are 5 as you can see here:

[W3C Markup Validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmyreclaim.de%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&st=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3%20http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices#line-311)

The first 4 of them are due to a shortcode i use its called "MD-Shortcodes" and a part of the Themesholic "Elite" Theme. Due to the fact that they got there own Markup i cant realy edit them in the Backend and i couldnt find something like a "part of html" file to edit those bugs.

The 5. Problem is very simple in the theorie.. its just a "alt="" " that is missing.. but(!) im using a plugin called ["Nelio External Featured Image"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/external-featured-image/) to embed the always updating pictures from a website. I can just manage there Size based on @Media resolutions in css and because of that and the fact that i dont get the picture in my library im pretty sure its created by some sort of .php or stuff like that.

I have no clue about php so it would be very cool if someone could check the files and tell me what to change to add a empty alt tag .. after a reupload of the plugin it should work like a charm.

I really appreciate that you invest a part of your lifetime in helping people! Thanks :).

Edit:

I found this in the nelio-efi-main.php. Would it work if i simply add a alt="" at the end of the first line?

```
$html = sprintf(
    '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" ' .
    'style="background:url(\'%s\') no-repeat center center;' .
    '-webkit-background-size:cover;' .
    '-moz-background-size:cover;' .
    '-o-background-size:cover;' .
    'background-size:cover;' .
    '%s%s" class="%s wp-post-image nelioefi" />',
    $image_url, $width, $height, $additional_classes );
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend editing any of the files in the plugin as they will get overwritten when you update the plugin.

There might be a way to hook into that plugin by extending it, but I'm not familiar with it. If you contact the plugin's developer, they could probably give you better insight.

To solve your immediate problem,

Instead of executing the shortcode within the content block, you could instead execute it from the PHP code via

```
do_shortcode("[<<the shortcode>>]")
```

Then wrap it in a str_replace, to add the src="".. something like -->

```
 echo  str_replace('<img','<img src=""',do_shortcode("[<<the shortcode>>]"));
```

Comment: Your answer makes me think that we misunderstand each other. The Shortcodes im talking about are just the little html problems. The fact that you are talking about PHP brings me to the assumption that you think its a shortcode adding the external picture. 

Anyways i wouldnt say that i have a problem with writing in the plugin's code. Im always a bit scared by updating since i destroyed some days of work in my younger years by updating a theme. Sorry if i did missunderstood you but my knowledge of PHP isnt even existing so i cant really imagine what your code does.

Comment: So actually they are the same thing, if you're using this plugin here --> http://kolakube.com/guides/using-md-shortcodes/ . When you add these shortcodes within the content area, it triggers code to be generated when the page is displayed. Alternatively, you can trigger these same shortcodes via PHP. You could take your page.php and create a custom template for the page in question. Then you could trigger the same shortcodes you're using within the content area, using the code above. If you post the shortcodes and your page.php code I may be able to help further..

Comment: If you're not comfortable editing PHP code, your best bet may be to reach out to the developer of the plugin and see if they can incorporate what you need in their next release

Comment: Ah well, now i learned how shortcodes work. Anyways, i found something out by myself and could solve the most of the problems. If you recheck the link you can see that there is just one error left, beside the alt tag one. And this is the double id usage one. Is there any way to find out where it is located or anything like that? Im pretty sure i didnt do that  ..

Comment: Looks like the following two lines of html are causing that problem -->  Line 101, Column 47: Duplicate ID page-container.
 **<div class="page-content" id="page-container">**
Warning Line 99, Column 38: The first occurrence of ID page-container was here.
**<div id="page-container" class="wide">** If I had to guess, I think you can remove it from the **<div class="page-content"** line. If we've been able to resolve your problem, could you kindly mark my reply as answered. If this doesn't help, if you post the file that you're using to display the page, I can help you ID the line of code to edit

Comment: Its a wordpress based website that does use a theme. I already did ask in the theme creator forums so he can tell me if it is on his site or on mine, than ill reply to you. Currently i cant say if the php thing is fixing my problem  because i dont use it so i cant vote your answer up  if i dont know that it work.

Comment: This works so well that I keep referring back to it when I need to execute a shortcode within the page's PHP